# In-place matrix transposition using rotations

Tags: correctness-proof, matrices, check-my-answer, in-place

Some time ago I invented an algorithm for in-place matrix transposition using rotations.

A matrix of size N×M is represented as a one-dimensional array of size N*M, which is also the future storage for the corresponding transposed M×N matrix.

The algorithm moves an element to its proper position in the representation for the transposed matrix rotating the sub-array of the array 1 element right, starting at the correct and ending at the current position of the element.

Let `matrix` be the array of size `N*M`, where `N` and `M` are the number of rows and columns in the original matrix (and the number of columns and rows in the transposed). Array indices are from `0` to `N*M-1`.

Let `dst` be the proper position for the element in the array for the transposed matrix, `src` — its current position, `src_inc` is the value addet to `src` to point to the "current position" of the next element to be moved. The algorithm starts with `dst = 1`, `src_inc = M` and `src = dst + src_inc - 1` (which is equal to `M`) (The element at the `0`-th position is already in its right place). After the first rotation, we increment `dst` by `1` and `src` by `src_inc` (which is `M`) **until** `dst` points to an element which should not be moved. This happens when `(dst + 1) % N` is `0`. In this case we skip the element (incrementing `dst` again), decrease `src_inc` by one and restore the initial relation between `src` and `dst` — `src = dst + src_inc - 1`.

Let me, instead of writing a pseudo-code, show the C++ code and add a state of the array before each rotation (plus the final result)

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
void inplace_transpose_using_rotations(T* matrix, int N, int M)
{
    int dst = 1;
    int src_inc = M;
    int src = dst + src_inc - 1;

    while (src < N*M && dst < src)
    {
        std::rotate(matrix + dst, matrix + src, matrix + src + 1); // rotate right for 1 position
        if ((dst + 1) % N != 0) {
            dst += 1;
            src += src_inc;
        } else {
            dst += 2;
            src_inc -= 1;
            src = dst + src_inc - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

(https://wandbox.org/permlink/XAWE1Fn64SxvEvth)

Original `3×5` matrix:

```
11 12 13 14 15 
21 22 23 24 25 
31 32 33 34 35
```

The trace (the first row is indices, the matrix is represented linearly, `dst` and `src` to the right are shown **before** the rotation, the result of the rotation is on the next line):

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 
11 12 13 14 15 21 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35 | dst = 01, src = 05
11 21 12 13 14 15 22 23 24 25 31 32 33 34 35 | dst = 02, src = 10
11 21 31 12 13 14 15 22 23 24 25 32 33 34 35 | dst = 04, src = 07
11 21 31 12 22 13 14 15 23 24 25 32 33 34 35 | dst = 05, src = 11
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 14 15 23 24 25 33 34 35 | dst = 07, src = 09
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 14 15 24 25 33 34 35 | dst = 08, src = 12
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33 14 15 24 25 34 35 | dst = 10, src = 11
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33 14 24 15 25 34 35 | dst = 11, src = 13
11 21 31 12 22 32 13 23 33 14 24 34 15 25 35 | final array
```

(the code producing the trace https://wandbox.org/permlink/3nhlwYoSz5GnWuUP)

And transposed matrix (reinterpretation of the array as a representation for a `5×3` matrix):

```
11 21 31 
12 22 32 
13 23 33 
14 24 34 
15 25 35
```

The algorithm is not optimal, it does [image: N(N-1)/2 M(M-1)/2] swaps (assuming the rotation is implemented as a chain of swaps), but it is short and seems to work.

However, I couldn't prove why it should work. I was just curious to try to transpose a matrix using rotations instead of chain of swaps following cycles and discovered that there is a relatively simple law how to select the next sub-array for rotation. Is this algorithm published anywhere?

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and (if possible) arguments of correctness. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: @dkaeae I've left the code, but added some explanation and a trace

Answer (score 1):

After the array is rotated with `dst == N - 1` (so the condition `(dst + 1) % N == 0` is about to fire), the tail of the array starting from index `N` looks like a representation of a N×(M-1) matrix with the values of the original matrix without the first column:

```
11 21 31 12 13 14 15 22 23 24 25 32 33 34 35
         ^ starting from here
```

looks like a representation of the

```
12 13 14 15
22 23 24 25
32 33 34 35
```

matrix

which immediately suggests how to simplify the algorithm:

```
template<typename T>
void inplace_transpose_using_rotations(T* matrix, int N, int M)
{
    if (N == 1 || M == 1)
        return;

    for (int dst = 1; dst != N; dst++)
        std::rotate(matrix + dst, matrix + dst * M, matrix + dst * M + 1);

    inplace_transpose_using_rotations(matrix + N, N, M - 1);
}
```

This explains how the algorithm works: rotations move first elements of each row into their proper position in the transposed matrix and at the same time shift the other elements to the right forming a representation of a smaller N×(M-1) matrix in the right side of the array. Then this smaller matrix is transposed, until we get a N×1 matrix.